# FB.Event.subscribe not working

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on a website and wanted to give my users an option to log-in using facebook.
I am successful at logging in but events are not working for me.

Whenever i logged in, the function "login" was not called.....I have tried assigning this login function to other button for checking it manually, the alert worked but it didnt get any response.
Here my Code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({appId: MY_APP_ID, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      login();
     });
};

 function login(){
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
   alert('You have successfully logged in, '+response.name+"!");
  }); 
 }

 (function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script');
   e.type = 'text/javascript';
   e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
 }());     </script>

<fb:login-button autologoutlink='true'   
  perms='email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream'></fb:login-button>
```

This is the facebook application setting:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried loading the all.js script in the `<head>` instead of `#fb-root`? Use the following:

```
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
```

instead of:

```
 (function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script');
   e.type = 'text/javascript';
   e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
 }());
```

[EDIT: updated sample]

> The SDK inserts elements into fb-root which expect to be positioned relative 
>     to the body or relative to an element close to the top of the page.

Which might replacing the SDK source as well.
resource: [Facebook Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

--
can you try to subscribe to other event and see if its work

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
  // do something with response
});
```

From Facebook documentation (try subscribing this instead)

> **auth.authResponseChange**
>      This event is fired for any auth related change as they all affect the session: login, logout, session refresh. Sessions are refreshed over time as long as the user is active with your app.
>
> **auth.statusChange**
>       Typically you will want to use the auth.authResponseChange event. But in rare cases, you want to distinguish between these three states:
>       1. Connected
>       2. Logged into Facebook but not connected with your application
>       3. Not logged into Facebook at all.

Comment: Still didnt worked....Also this is the error i am getting in response when checked manually -> code: 2500
message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
type: "OAuthException"

Comment: the event you subscribe `auth.login - fired when the auth status changes from unknown to connected`. probably u always connected? secondly, whatever you trying to access need to have the accessToken when the user authenticated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

Comment: I've updated my question with the facebook application settings.

Comment: no i mean, u said that "Whenever i logged in, the function "login" not called", the following `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', {...})` will only be triggered if you not login and changed to login. see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1 (New User)

Facebook Login Button's Text: "Login"
User State: User not connected

Now user clicks on login and completes the login flow.

Button's text changes to "Log Out" and this is the only time when`'auth.login'` triggers.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {     
        // do something with response                   
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // user connected                        
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                alert(response.name + " " + response.id);
            });
        }
});
```

Scenario 2 (Existing User)

If a user who is logged in to Facebook and has already authorized your app visits your app then the user automatically get's connected and Login Button's text is "Log Out".
In this case add the following code into the `fbAsyncInit function`:

```
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // connected
                    alert(response.name + " " + response.id);
                }
            });
```

`FB.getLoginStatus` is called everytime the page refreshes but you can also call it anytime in your app by embedding it into a javascript function.